# DateTime conversion issue in objective-c and SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime, datetime-format

I am stuck in a very strange situation. I have a database in SQLite having column "DATETIME". In this column there is a value say "2011-10-05 12:00:46". I am converting this by using NSDateFormatter, I set the NSDateFormatter like this -

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"];
[df dateFromString:completedDate];
```

when i run my project in iPhone simulater this works fine and i got the result as i want. When i debug same project in device and check the value of object type NSDate i got null value.

Please tell me what wrong i am doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. Capital `M` is meant for Month. For Minute you should use small `m`. Your date format should look like this.

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```